# Samba system calls for reading/writing files from/to NAS issued from Windows desktop client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, io

Windows desktop machine is connected via 1GB Ehternet cable to personal NAS (under development) with Ubuntu on it. While reading and writing files (> 1GB size) from/to NAS strace was conducted to monitor samba process system calls, due to the fact tha samba is the one which is doing hard work.

Below is the small section of the strace output:

```
mmap2(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb4eaf000 <0.000075>
pread(31, "\255\343.\372e\357F\315\357\247\21o{\331\223\336\216\235\367\\#L\312\220W\323\226\303\302\21\35\336"..., 1048576, 13631488) = 1048576 <0.010848>
writev(34, [{"\3261\347S\205\2\347\325\316\325\214LT{\337\256!\351\246\266\342b\204i\347\221:x$\r\5\227"..., 999020}], 1) = 49640 <0.000451>
gettimeofday({6146, 475882}, NULL)      = 0 <0.000282>
gettimeofday({6146, 476842}, NULL)      = 0 <0.000152>
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLHUP}], 4, 57236) = 1 ([{fd=34, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000202>
```

This continues until all read bytes are written to cache, after which, new  `pread` system call follows and so on. (before that `mmap2`-ed memory is unmaped)

What I notice is that later called `writev` functions return larger and larger bytes number, e.g.

```
mmap2(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb4eaf000 <0.000304>
pread(31, "\343\367\235\227Q;\3717\240<\nl\326ff\0\361 J\37\253T\247\352\207\376\372\273\341\360\370y"..., 1048576, 458227712) = 1048576 <0.032897>
writev(34, [{"\t\21\6\301\366hPq\274\373\353x\332X\377\310\275<J\4z\261\0\227\24\230\256\350\300\16\355\203"..., 674900}], 1) = 373760 <0.002618>
gettimeofday({6164, 906348}, NULL)      = 0 <0.000149>
gettimeofday({6164, 907318}, NULL)      = 0 <0.000149>
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN|POLLHUP}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLHUP}], 4, 38805) = 1 ([{fd=34, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000199>
```

- Why is it happening? Does is depend on I/O scheduler? Used I/O scheduler is ROW.
- Can I somehow influence on the read and write I/O *block sizes*? I want to speed up the things, so why not start with large `writev` *block sizes* from the very beginning. If *block size* is the right name for return values for `pread` and `writev` functions. It's hard to distinguish terminology, since there is evidently *block size* for files as well as *block size* for disks.
- When I'm using `dd` for example, am I via `bs` parameter influencing file *block size*? Since disk *block size* is determined on the formatting time and there is no way of changing it on the fly.
- And lastly, can I somehow prevent `gettimeofday` function call, since I don't see the need for it, or I'm wrong?

Sorry if some of the questions reveal alarming lack of knowledge, but I'm really trying to clear all the terminology along with my baby steps to the Linux realm.